# Avoid repetition in many-to-one relationship

Tags: hibernate

I'm developing an application that stores the weather info for a city on a given date.
My WeatherInfo class looks something like this:

```
@Entity
public class WeatherInfo implements ResponseObject
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column
    @Temporal(value=TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonProperty("date")
    @JsonSerialize(using=JsonUtils.TimestampSerializer.class)
    private Date date;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonProperty("city")
    private City city;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonProperty("weather")
    private Collection<Weather> weather;


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private WeatherInfo()
    {
    //Used by Hibernate
    }

    public WeatherInfo(Date aDate, City aCity,Collection<Weather> aWeatherCollection){
    this.date = aDate;
    this.city = aCity;
    this.weather = aWeatherCollection;

    }

}
```

The problem is that if I save a WeatherInfo for a given city 3 times, 3 entries of the same city are added to the City table. I assumed that this would not happen if I specified a Many-to-one relationship between WeatherInfo and City. How do I stop this from happening?

**UPDATE**

I get the WeatherInfo from OpenWeatherMap REST service and map their City and Weather objects to my own.

```
public OWMWeatherInfoAdapter(org.openweathermap.WeatherInfo aWeatherInfo)
    {
    super();
    super.setDate(aWeatherInfo.getTimestamp());
    super.setCity(getCity(aWeatherInfo));
    super.setWeather(getWeatherCollection(aWeatherInfo));

    }

    private City getCity((org.openweathermap.WeatherInfo aWeatherInfo){
    Synopsis sys = aWeatherInfo.getSynopsis();
    Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(aWeatherInfo.getCoordinates().getLongitude(),aWeatherInfo.getCoordinates().getLatitude());
    return new City(aWeatherInfo.getCityName(),sys.getCountry(),sys.getSunrise(),sys.getSunset(),coord);
    }

    private Collection<Weather> getWeatherCollection((org.openweathermap.WeatherInfo aWeatherInfo){

    Collection<org.openweathermap.Weather> owmWeathers = aWeatherInfo.getWeathers();
    for(org.openweathermap.Weather owmWeather : owmWeathers){
        super.getWeather().add(new Weather(owmWeather.getMain(),owmWeather.getDescription()));
    }

    return super.getWeather();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code where you call the constructors of the City and WeatherInfo classes. I’m pretty sure the issue is there, not in the code you posted.

Comment: I've attached the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getCity(WeatherInfo)` method returns a *new* city each time it is called. This mean that if it is called 3 times, it will return 3 *different* cities, eventually leading to 3 rows in the CITY table. If the `getCity(WeatherInfo)` returns 3 identical cities, it will still be 3 different objects and hence 3 rows in the CITY table.

In order to avoid this, you need to check if an instance of a given city already exists before creating a new one. If you can assume that no two cities can share the same name, you can first lookup cities in the DB by their name:

```
private getCity(WeatherInfo info) {
    Query query = session.createQuery("from City where name = :name"); // assume field session is available
    query.setParameter("name", info.getCityName());
    City city = query.uniqueResult();
    if (city == null) {
        // Only in this case should we create a new City
        Synopsis sys = info.getSynopsis();
        Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(iherInfo.getCoordinates().getLongitude(), info.getCoordinates().getLatitude());
        city = new City(info.getCityName(), sys.getContry(), sys.getSunrise(), coord);
        session.save(city);
    }
    return city;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks :) I integrated the check-city-exists code in the saveWeatherInfo method in the DAO class.